# How to display only the last result of a 'for' inside a 'function', in Javascript

Tags: function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function to calculate remainder, and I would like to get last result of the 'for'.

//Here's the function:

```
function remainderCalculator(value1,value2){
    for(i = value1;i >= value2;i = i - value2){
        console.log(i - value2);
    }
}

remainderCalculator(52,14);
```

Need some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: please make your request more clear

Comment: Sure, the remainder between 52 and 14 is 10, but I run this function, it will show me: 38, 24 and then 10, I would like to know if there's a way to get 10 without seeing 38 and 24

Comment: Just move the `console.log` outside the `for` loop and `console.log(i)` instead

Comment: nevermind, I figured out the end user will only see the result on the browser like this: